# If a website has two DOCTYPEs with iframes which one does it use?

Tags: html, iframe

Hey so I have this site: pillower.com and I couldn't figure out how to configure the server (apache) to use my domain so I just masked and forwarded it from my provider (go daddy)

But I noticed that when you go to my site the source code shows go daddy's DOCTYPE (html 4) then it has an iframe (I think) with my servers ip) which then has an HTML 5 DOCTYPE

So I'm wondering, will my site be limiting in any way if its using the old DOCTYPE or does it have the html 5 one?

Comment: It depends on the exact go daddy doctype ("html 4" does not narrow it down sufficiently) and on the browser being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inner frame is isolated from the outer frame's `DOCTYPE`. That said, there are other advantages to having the domain point to your server rather than to some other server and using an `iframe`.